# Multiply each column from 2D array with each column from another 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have two Numpy arrays `x` with shape `(m, i)` and `y` with shape `(m, j)` (so the number of rows is the same). I would like to multiply each column of `x` with each column of `y` element-wise so that the result is of shape `(m, i*j)`.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
x = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 3))
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 2))
```

This creates the following two arrays `x`:

```
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

and `y`:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

Now the result should be:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Currently, I've implemented this operation with two nested loops over the columns of `x` and `y`:

```
def _mult(x, y):
    r = []
    for xc in x.T:
        for yc in y.T:
            r.append(xc * yc)
    return np.array(r).T
```

However, I'm pretty sure that there must be a more elegant solution that I can't seem to come up with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(y[:,None]*x[...,None]).reshape(x.shape[0],-1)
```

**Explanation**

As inputs, we have -

```
y : 10 x 2
x : 10 x 3
```

With `y[:,None]`, we are introducing a new axis between the existing two dims, thus creating a `3D` array version of it. This keeps the first axis as the first one in `3D` version and pushes out the second axis as the third one.

With `x[...,None]`, we are introducing a new axis as the last one by pushing up the two existing dims as the first two dims to result in a `3D` array version.

To summarize, with the introduction of new axes, we have -

```
y : 10 x 1 x 2
x : 10 x 3 x 1
```

With `y[:,None]*x[...,None]`, there would be `broadcasting` for both `y` and `x`, resulting in an output array with a shape of `(10,3,2)`. To get to the final output array of shape `(10,6)`, we just need to merge the last two axes with that reshape.

Comment: "complicated" hack but very concise! +1

Comment: can you add some explanation here? it's concise but not explanatory.

Comment: @kmario23 Added some explanation, check it out!