# How to perform tensor production in Python/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy 2D-arrays and I want to perform this:

```
a_ij * b_ik = c_ijk
```

How can I make it with numpy?

Comment: Since you are performing `elementwise multiplication` keeping the first axis common, you can simply use `broadcasting` : `a[...,None]*b[:,None,:]`. See [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38715383/3293881) for explanation on it.

Answer (score 4):

`einsum` is tailor made for this task

```
a_ij * b_ik = c_ijk

c = np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', a, b)
```

===================

But as Divakar shows, no summation is implied, so plain multiplication works just as well, `a[...,None]*b[:,None,:]`.